# Issue with CollectionViewSource

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

I am having a small issue here:

In my Code I have an ObservableCollection with some Items:

```
myCalenderItems = new ObservableCollection<CalendarItem>();
```

To have the list sorted, I created a CollectionViewSource, which I bound to a datagrid in code behind:

```
 ICollectionView mySortedCalenderItems = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(myCalenderItems);

  mySortedCalenderItems.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("Day", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
  mySortedCalenderItems.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("Time", ListSortDirection.Ascending));

  MainGrid.DataContext = mySortedCalenderItems;
  CalendarDataGrid.ItemsSource = mySortedCalenderItems;
```

The XAML for the Datagrid looks as the following:

```
 <DataGrid Name="CalendarDataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserSortColumns="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Day" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource WeekDayEnum}}" Width="*" SelectedValueBinding="{Binding Day, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Time" Binding="{Binding Time}" Width="*" IsReadOnly="False"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Value" Binding="{Binding Value}" Width="*" IsReadOnly="False"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGrid.GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle ContainerStyle="{StaticResource GroupHeaderStyle}">
                    <GroupStyle.Panel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <DataGridRowsPresenter/>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </GroupStyle.Panel>
                </GroupStyle>
            </DataGrid.GroupStyle>
        </DataGrid>
```

Further I also want to be able to edit the values using other controls beside the datagrid, e.g

```
<ComboBox Text="{Binding Path=Day}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"/>
```

And here is where I have my problem. When changing the day in the datagrid the sorting works, but when changing it via the combobox control it does change in the datagrid but it is not re-sorted. 
(A re-sorting is done when changing another property of the before modified item)

Do you have any ideas what is wrong here?

Regards

PS:
Entire XAML

```
<UserControl
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyProject" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="520" d:DesignWidth="840">

<UserControl.Resources>
    <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="WeekDayEnum" MethodName="GetValues"
                    ObjectType="{x:Type System:Enum}">
        <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
            <x:Type TypeName="local:WeekDay"/>
        </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
    </ObjectDataProvider>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid x:Name="MainGrid" Grid.Row="0">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="240"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="180"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Content="Weekly" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        <DataGrid x:Name="CalendarDataGrid" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{Binding}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserSortColumns="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Day" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource WeekDayEnum}}" Width="*" SelectedValueBinding="{Binding Day, Mode=TwoWay}"  />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Time" Binding="{Binding Time}" Width="*" IsReadOnly="False"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Value" Binding="{Binding Value}" Width="*" IsReadOnly="False"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>

        <Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="70"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Label Grid.Row="0" Content="Day" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="20,0,0,0"/>
            <Label Grid.Row="1" Content="Time" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="20,0,0,0"/>
            <Label Grid.Row="2" Content="Value" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="20,0,0,0"/>

            <ComboBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right"  VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="100" Text="{Binding Path=Day}"  IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"/>
            <TextBox Grid.Row="1"  Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="100" Text="{Binding Path=Time, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            <TextBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap"  Width="100" Text="{Binding Path=Value, Mode=TwoWay}"/>

        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Try calling `mySortedCalenderItems.Refresh();` in the `SelectionChanged` event of the `ComboBox`

Comment: If MainGrid is parent of DataGrid there is no need for

    CalendarDataGrid.ItemsSource = mySortedCalenderItems;

Comment: Call refresh at SelectionChanged Event gives me this error:
'Refresh' is not allowed during an AddNew or EditItem transaction.

Comment: I now called mySortedCalenderItems.Refresh() at the LostFocus Event of the ComboBox which somehow does the job, but this cant be the real solution :(

Answer (score 0):

The combobox code in XAML is not setup properly. To work properly you will need to set the `SelectedValue` property. (This may need to be tweaked a bit, but it gives you the idea).

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource WeekDayEnum}}" 
                       SelectedValue="{Binding Path=Day, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

---

Let me give an example of one combo box changing another...

For example I have this data type of:

```
public class PriceItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
}
```

and here is the data list of values which is saved on my VM as `Items`.

```
Items = new List<PriceItem>()
{
    new PriceItem() { Name = "Alpha", Price=100 },
    new PriceItem() { Name = "Beta",  Price=200 },
};
```

**Scenario**
Two combo boxes, both bound to the `Items` data. One combo box shows the `Name` in its dropdown while the other shows the `Price`. The `Name` combobox controls the price combo box, when it changes the price changes as well.

```
<ComboBox x:Name="comboName" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" />
<ComboBox x:Name="comboValue"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
          DisplayMemberPath="Price"
          SelectedValuePath="Price"
          SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedItem.Price, ElementName=comboName, Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

In action both combo boxes are blank. But whenever I select the first one it changes the second. All using the same data/data objects.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the info, but this doesn't really fix my problem which is the refresh of the CollectionViewSource. When changing the (Day) value in the combobox, also the value in the Datagrid changes, but the sorting is not triggered. When changing the (Day) value in the Datagrid directly it is automatically beeing resorted.